# Erlang: New utility function which gets a record's field names from a known set of records

Tags: erlang

I want to create a function which is able to return a list of a records field names. There are a set number of records in the project but defined in different modules. However at compile time they haven't been created yet.

```erlang
print_record(Record) ->
  [Name|Values] = tuple_to_list(Record),
  case Name of
    test_record_one ->
      record_info(fields, test_record_one);
    test_record_two ->
      record_info(fields, test_record_two);
    ...
    Else ->
      Else
  end.
```

The issue with this code is when compiling, the compiler returns with the records being undefined. This is true however I was wondering if there is a way to get around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand on what you mean by `at compile time they haven't been created yet`, because record definition must be at least defined at compile time.

Let's say the record definition is defined in a header file (.hrl) which is accessible by your utility module.

```
%%Filename: records.hrl

-record(test_record_one, {field1, field2}).
-record(test_record_two, {field3, field4}).
```

And the utility module

```
-module(test_util). 

-include("records.hrl"). %%assuming this hrl file is in the same directory, otherwise need to use include_lib directive
-export([print_record/1]).
-export([test_1/0]).
-export([test_2/0]).

print_record(Record) ->
  [Name| Values] = tuple_to_list(Record), 
  case Name of
    test_record_one -> record_info(fields, test_record_one);
    test_record_two -> record_info(fields, test_record_two);
               Else -> ok
  end.

test_1() ->
  test_util:print_record(#test_record_one{}).

test_2() ->
  test_util:print_record(#test_record_two{field3 = "abc", field4 = 100}).
```

Testing directly from shell

```
%%Must inform Erlang shell on the record definition
> rd(test_record_one, {field1, field2}).
test_record_one
> rd(test_record_two, {field3, field4}).
test_record_two
> test_util:print_record(#test_record_one{}). 
[field1,field2]
> test_util:print_record(#test_record_two{field3 = "abc", field4 = 100}).
[field3,field4]
```

Testing by calling the test functions

```
> test_util:test_1().
[field1,field2]
> test_util:test_2().
[field3,field4]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use [the `exprecs` parse transform](https://github.com/uwiger/parse_trans/blob/master/doc/exprecs.md).  Pick a module that includes the parse transform and exports the relevant functions - let's call the module `records`:

```
-module(records).
%% the records are defined in records.hrl
-include("records.hrl").
-compile({parse_transform, exprecs}).
-export_records([test_record_one, test_record_two]).
```

You can then define `print_record` like this:

```
print_record(Record) ->
  records:'#info-'(element(1, Record), fields).
```